# Approaching limit for non-selective query: How to find the offending query?

Tags: soql, selectivity

I am getting following warning email but can not find out where exactly the problem is. I am facing problem in finding out which SOQL query is causing issue. Any help will be much appreciated :)

Operation: /clients/sidepanel/sidepanelcontainer.apexp

By user/organization: 005i0000003SqTj/00Di0000000h4ve

Caused the following Apex resource warnings:

Approaching limit for non-selective query against large object type (more than 100000 rows). Current size is approximately 83064 rows. When the limit is reached, the query will fail. Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing. 
Even if a field is indexed a filter might still not be selective when: 
1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null) 2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs many times) null

(these emails can be disabled from the user detail page for this user)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the data usage page of setup to see what type of object has (roughly) 83,064 rows. I'd afraid you might have to work backwards from there, since this message doesn't call out nearly enough information to nail down a specific query as being at fault.

Until a table has over 100,000 rows the normal requirements around selectivity are not enforced, and in this case your warning is that the table is approaching that limit, which is why I suggest using the data useage page to figure out just which table that is.

Comment: I know the object for which the error is thrown.  But how to identify which query?  I's using this object is many classes (25) and many triggers (10).  There are lots of queries on it.  How do I know which query is causing it?

Answer (score 0):

from the warning it looks like you code has reached Governance Limit. Try extracting the Debug log by setting the loglevel for your Apex Class to Error/Debug. and Use Developer console > View Log Panel to checkout the error location.